# ::marker image content size relative to font size

Tags: css

In css I want to style the marker to be a certain image. However it becomes to big and I can't change the size of it. I've seen other solutions but they worked only with px. I need the image to be relative to the font size.

```
::marker {
    content: url("img.png");
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Comment: `height:1em` maybe ?

Comment: Can you show us the particular image because although you could get it 'relative to' in some sense with either a width or a height it's going to depend rather on how 'like' a character it looks aspect ratio-wise.

Comment: @AHaworth It's just a png image of a green plus sign which is 1280x1275.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to make it work using `::marker` so this is a "hacky" way. Maybe someone will come with a better solution.

Example image is originally 200x300px. You control the size using `font-size` in `li`.

```css
/* let's create a list with fixed width and visible browser to see text wrapping */
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 450px;
}

/* different font sizes to see it working */
li + li {
  font-size: 20px;
}

li + li + li {
  font-size: 36px;
}

/* hide default marker */
li::marker {
  content: '';
}

/* we use position absolute, to this is our reference to read the font size */
li {
  position: relative;
}

/* create a box with a size of 1em, add background and position how you like it */
li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/163/200/300);
  transform: translate(-100%);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Normal text example here</li>
  <li>Multiline text example here...now repeat. Multiline text example here...now repeat. Multiline text example here...now repeat. Multiline text example here...now repeat. Multiline text example here...now repeat. Size: 20px;
  <li>Biggest text here - size 36px</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Usually I try to avoid hacky approaches as it gives me little room to learn and understand but your solution is helpful nonetheless so thank you. Only one issue remains which is that I would like the marker to be vertically centered relative to the text.

Comment: I too couldn't find a solution using marker so this is probably the best way forward. How though do you define vertically centered when it comes to fonts? They can differ as to how much is below/above the baseline. Maybe could alter the position dependent on the particular font in use? But can never be sure of which is being used. Am a bit stuck.

Comment: Vertically? Change transform to `transform: translate(-100%, -50%);` and add `top: 50%;`